# Setting up Oracle XE on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, linux, oracle-xe, setup

I'm trying to set up oracle-xe on my Linux machine. I just need an environment to play with Oracle SQL; this is not for production.

When I try to start SQLPLUS I keep getting one of the following errors:

```
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error
```

There are quite a few posts regarding similar problems, but even after trying many different "solutions" I'm still lost.

I'm probably doing something horribly wrong. See the following outputs:

```
[oracle@roshan ~]$ whoami
oracle
[oracle@roshan ~]$ pwd
/usr/lib/oracle
[oracle@roshan ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
[oracle@roshan ~]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
PLSExtProc
[oracle@roshan ~]$ cat product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

SQL_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
[oracle@roshan ~]$ product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl start    

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-OCT-2017 12:24:03

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
[oracle@roshan ~]$ product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-OCT-2017 12:24:07

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                22-OCT-2017 12:21:18
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 2 min. 48 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /usr/lib/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/roshan/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=roshan.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@roshan ~]$ sqlplus SYSTEM/foobar@localhost:8080/PLSExtProc


SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 22 12:24:14 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener


Enter user-name: %                                                              [oracle@roshan ~]$ sqlplus SYSTEM/foobar@localhost:1521/PLSExtProc


SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 22 12:24:27 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error


Enter user-name: %   
[oracle@roshan ~]$ su
Password: 
[root@roshan oracle]# /etc/rc.d/oracle-xe status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-OCT-2017 12:32:06

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                22-OCT-2017 12:21:18
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 10 min. 47 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /usr/lib/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /usr/lib/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/roshan/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=roshan.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Does any of these look very wrong?

Comment: In addition to my comments as an answer, what flavor of Linux is this? You need to be aware that Oracle is only certified for a small number of Linux distros, and Ubuntu is not one of them.

Comment: @EdStevens: This is on Arch Linux.

Comment: ArchLinux is NOT one of the certified distros.  Oracle Linux, Red Hat, or Suse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you should set ORACLE_SID to 'xe', not 'PLSExtProc'.  'PLSExtProc' is a special case for external procedures.  In over 25 years, I've *never* had a reason to use it.

2) when you call sqlplus like this:

```
sqlplus username/password
```

you are calling for an interprocess connection, and bypassing all network issues, includeing the listener.  The listener is only involved for requests that come across the network.

When you call sqlplus like this:

```
sqlplus username/password@mydb
```

you are calling for a network connection, with the details to be resolved from the 'mydb' entry in the tnsnames.ora file

When you call sqlplus like this (as suggested by @Balazs Papp)

```
sqlplus username/password@localhost:1521:xe
```

You are calling for a network connection, but bypassing the use of tnsnames.ora and supplying the critical information (hostname, port, sid) directly.  Not that all three elements must match what is reported by 'lisnrctl status'.  In your case the host is not 'localhost' but rather 'roshan.localdomain'.

The fact that your client (sqlplus) and the database are on the same machine doesn't matter.  If you use a syntax that calls for a network connection, the request still goes through all the network protocols.

You can read more about how oracle handles networked connections at http://edstevensdba.com/category/oracle-tns/ and http://edstevensdba.com/category/oracle-listener/

Comment: So by 'setting' the SID do you just mean exporting $ORACLE_SID=XE? Or do you mean using XE in the sqlplus command? So it doesn't run on localhost. In fact, I just realised that I can't access the Oracle homepage in the web browser on localhost:8080 any more. This used to work yesterday before I started playing with ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID and the Oracle user on my system. Should I be using the Oracle user for all these commands anyway? Even if I use roshan.localdomain I get the `ORA-01033` as mentioned in the comment to Balazs Papp's answer. What should I do?

Comment: If you reference the sid (XE) in your sqlplus command (sqlplus scott/tiger@XE) then it doesn't matter what ORACLE_SID is set to.  ORACLE_SID comes into play when you want an inter-process call, not for a network call.  If you want an inter-process call, then yes, 'export ORACLE_SID=XE'.  But since you are on an unsupported distro , this all may be a moot point.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to set up a VM with a supported distro and follow a tutorial for that. I will get back to you if it doesn't work, but this answer has already helped me understand it much better. :)

Comment: Setting up a vm with a supported distro would be a very good idea.  I'd recommend Oracle Linux.  It's free.  And by setting up a vm you can treat it just like a live server behind a blast door in a lights-out data center, accessing with client tools from the host os.  I have several vms under VBox on both my personal and company machines.  Be aware of the network considerations.  See http://edstevensdba.com/virtual-test-lab/configuring-the-oracle-virtualbox-network/

Answer (score 1):

The listener listens on the default port: 1521. You are trying to log in using port 8080.

Instead of this:

```
sqlplus SYSTEM/foobar@localhost:8080/PLSExtProc
```

Try this:

```
sqlplus SYSTEM/foobar@localhost:1521/XE
```

The port 8080 is used by APEX, you can log in there from a browser.

Comment: Trying that command yields an error I haven't seen before: `ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`

Comment: At a command prompt:  'export ORACLE_SID=XE', then 'sqlplus / as sysdba', then at the resulting SQL prompt, 'startup'.  Copy the text from the entire session and paste it back here.